# ERROR_PIPE_BUSY при переподключении к именованному каналу

Tags: c#, c++

Нужно организовать межпроцессорное взаимодействие через именованные каналы. На стороне сервера делается так:

```
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances);
pipeServer.WaitForConnectionAsync();
...
if (pipeServer.IsConnected) {
     // send data.
}
```

Клиент подключается следующим образом:

```
hPipe = CreateFile(lpszPipeName,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Pipe open error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    EXIT();
}

DWORD dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_BYTE;
if (!SetNamedPipeHandleState(hPipe, &dwMode, NULL, NULL))
{
    printf("Set pipe handle state error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    EXIT();
}

// read write data.
```

При переподключении возникает ошибка: 231 `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`. 
Странно, что после отключения клиента `pipeServer.IsConnected` имеет значение `True`, пока сервер не попытается прочитать или отправить данные через канал (там ожидаемое `IOException`).

Отключаю так:

```
DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

Comment: `ConnectNamedPipe` и `DisconnectNamedPipe` - это функции, которые должны вызываться на стороне *сервера*.

Comment: А как клиенту изъявить своё желание отключиться?

Comment: Просто `CloseHandle`. Пример простого клиента можно посмотреть здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client. Обратите внимание, что в случае `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY` они делают `WaitNamedPipe` и затем снова повторяют попытку `CreateFile`. Но для всего этого нужно, чтобы сервер тоже вел себя правильно.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как понять серверу, что клиент отключён. Просто попробовать чтение и запись в канал и, если возникает `IOException`, вызвать `PipeServer.Disconnect()`? Просто `IsConnected` не устанавливается в `False` после отключения клиента...